# Losing single quote on replacing aws keys in file using gitattributes and gitconfig

Tags: git

99% there in replacing access keys in a file that gets checked out.
I'm losing the single quotes on checkout

git checkout AppConfig.groovy

```
  accessKey =  GARB//AGE
```

but I really want

```
  accessKey =  'GARB//AGE'
```

here's my .gitattributes and ~/.gitconfig

```
AppConfig.groovy filter=awsRdsBotKeys


[filter "awsRdsBotKeys"]
        clean = sed -e 's/secretKey = .*/secretKey = ''/'
        smudge = sed -e 's:secretKey = .*:secretKey = 'GARB//AGE':'
```

Comment: I created a github repo to test your fix out.   https://github.com/joshuacalloway/gitexplore

Comment: I no longer believe in .gitconfig and .gitattributes for securing private information.  Am leaning now to environment variables.

Comment: https://github.com/joshuacalloway/howtosecureawskeys

Answer (score 2):

Try:

`sed -e 's:secretKey = .*:secretKey = '\''GARB//AGE'\'':'`

Turns out you have to escape the single quotes [from the bash itself](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33005). I just learned as well! See working example below:

```
echo "secretKey = FSIL38908LDKA" | sed -e 's:secretKey = .*:secretKey = '\''GARB//AGE'\'':'
```

Comment: getting error "fatal: bad config file line 8 in /home/jc/.gitconfig".

Comment: Please test with gitconfig and git checkout ( AND not with command line sed )